# Irreducibility of $2x^3-3x^2+6$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

The following statement is given, i need to check whether its true\false.

There exists a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $F\not\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $$F \cong \mathbb Q[X]/(2X^3 − 3X^2 + 6).$$

My attempt:

I thought since its cubic polynomial it will have a real solution, how do I show its not in $\mathbb Q$, and then the fact that $F\not\subseteq\mathbb R$?

Ans - Eisenstein and Rational root test, settle the first part. How to show that $F\not\subseteq\mathbb R$.

I know for a fact that this is a true statement.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenienvce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1. A rational root $p/q$  of $f(x):=2x^3-3x^2+6$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ is such that $p$ divides $6$ and $q$ divides $2$ (See the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)).

Hint 2. Note that $f'(x)=6x(x-1)$,  $x=0$ is a local maximum and $x=1$ is a local minimum with $f(1)=5>0$. Show that from this it follows that the roots are not all real.

Comment: how do I show the second part?

Comment: @rhombicosicodecahedron Note that $(2x^3-3x^2+6)'=6x(x-1)=0$,  $x=0$ is a local maximum and $x=1$ is a local minimum.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Rational root theorem. $\hphantom{imaginary space}$

Comment: how do i show the second part?

Comment: @rhombicosicodecahedron, do you mean $F\not\subseteq\mathbb R$? Well, $F$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ that contains $\mathbb Q$ and the roots of your polynomial. So, if all roots were real, it would follow that $F\subseteq\mathbb R$. Thus, you need to show that...?

Comment: ahh right, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from Eisensteins's criterion, with $p=3$.

Comment: Oh right. I got $2x^3$ and that had roots in Z3, so ignored it. stupid on my part. Thanks. How do I show the second part?